# Adding "->" in Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, object, methods

Ok so I'm fairly new to objective c and i'm building a concordance class, inside the class i got a method which adds a word from a book into a a _ListofPtrsToUniqueWords, uniqueWord is another class i built for storing the word being cataloged, well in c++ my method Adds the UniqueWord to an Array of Unique Words, if it already exist its skips the word but it add a line number to the _CurrentLineArray list, this is the method i used on C++

```
   /* Attempts to add a word to the concordance. If it already exists, the existing     entry is updated with the new line. */
void Concordance::add(const string word, const int line)
{
   int insertion, index;
    UniqueWord *uw = new UniqueWord(word, line);//creates the uniqueWord object
    insertion = newIndex(*uw, index);//figures out where my word belongs in my array to be alphabetized 
    if (insertion == -1)
      {
    // The word already exists - add a line number.
    delete uw;
    ListOfUniqueWordsPtrs[index]->addLine(line);//I'm trying to do this in Objective C. 
//My friend recommended i do this but i never asks what exactly does it do, addLine is a Unique word method
    }
    else
    {
    ListOfUniqueWordsPtrs.insert(ListOfUniqueWordsPtrs.begin() + insertion, uw);
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to do the same in Objective C but i don't understand what this symbol does "->", my friend just recommended i do this but i don't understand what it does and how can i implament this in Objective C

```
-(void) add:(NSString *)currentWordBeingCatalog and:(NSNumber*)CurrentLineNumber{
NSInteger insertion, index=0;

UniqueWord *CurrentWord=[[UniqueWord alloc] initWithString:currentWordBeingCatalog andline:CurrentLineNumber];
insertion=[self NewIndexToFindOutIf:CurrentWord is:[NSNumber numberWithLong:index]];
if(insertion==-1){
    /*If the word already exist, it would delete the word and add the line number to the _linenumber NSMutableArray*/
    CurrentWord=NULL;
    [_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords objectAtIndex:index]->[CurrentWord addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber]];//This is where i'm trying to figure out what to do
}else{
    [_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords insertObject:CurrentWord atIndex:(0+insertion)];
 }

}
```

I hope i give you guys enough information on this code, thank you

Comment: It might be easier if your naming was more similar between the two, but is this what you want? `[[_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords objectAtIndex:index] addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber]]` You don't want `->`. You get the object via `objectAtIndex`, then call something on that by adding another set of `[]` around it and adding the message name. Look at `[[UniqueWord alloc] initWithString...` as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax you are looking for:

```
[[_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords objectAtIndex:index] addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber];
```

... which is to say, you're asking the array to return one of its elements, and then you're asking that element to add a line number.

You can break it down like this if you prefer:

```
UniqueWord *existingWord = [_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords objectAtIndex:index];
[existingWord addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber];
```

You can also use array subscripting directly on `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` objects, so if `_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords` is an `NSMutableArray`, you can do this:

```
UniqueWord *existingWord = _ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords[index];
[existingWord addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber];
```

or this:

```
[_ArrayOfPtrsToUniqueWords[index] addALineNumberToCurrentLineNumberArray:CurrentLineNumber];
```

Comment: Thank you this is the exact explanation i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The `->` does something similar in Objective-C to what it does in C++, it is placed after a pointer to an object to access it's instance variables (in C++ it is also used to call methods, whereas in Objective-C the `[instance methodName]` syntax is used). Properties are usually preferred to the `->` notation in Objective-C however. It's use in your code seems erroneous, rob mayoff did a pretty good job of rectifying it.

Comment: would the example from @crashmtr in his comment be would i be looking for? sorry, i honestly dont know what the symbol did at all